# AJAX Functionality

Tags: ajax

In order to  enable AJAX Functionality , which control is placed on the page..?

Comment: Gah! Come on people, give us context, we're not psychic!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about ASP.NET, you'll need the ScriptManager and the UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

For AJAX functionality the page (i.e. it's Javascript) uses the [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object.

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for but since you haven't asked for a specific server side technology...

Answer (score 0):

The main AJAX control that you have to add to your web pages in order to enable ASP.NET AJAX functionality is the ScriptManager control.

If you have master pages you may also use ScriptManagerProxy control.

After adding ScriptManager on to a page, you can add other ASP.NET AJAX controls on the page.

On the other side, if you are just looking for generix AJAX style functionality, you have the JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object.